# MariaDB reviews a lot of rows when using index on uuid with null values

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, query-optimization

We got a database with a card table

```
CREATE TABLE `card` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `parent_card_id` char(36) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `table_parent_card_id_idx` (`parent_card_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `card_collection_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`collection_id`) REFERENCES `collection` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

The card can have a reference to its parent, if the field is null its means that the row is the main object.

In the current database we 20838 row, and only 5 of the cards are having a parent_card_id.

When i look a the explain of both queries, it looks like the first one don't uses the index correctly. The real table and query are larger and different, but made it simpeler for this question.

```
EXPLAIN
 SELECT
    card.id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(`child`.`id`)
        FROM `card` AS `child`
        WHERE `child`.`parent_card_id` = `card`.`id`
    ) 
FROM card
WHERE card.id IN  ('0a4f5e08-496f-4a43-994a-1ed1bc28f8fb', '51d755a6-74ef-4c36-bc5b-a3a313d340f4')
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | card | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 144 | 2 |  | Using where; Using index |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | child | ref | card_parent_card_id_idx | card_parent_card_id_idx | 145 | card.id | 10269 | Using index |

```
EXPLAIN
 SELECT
    card.id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(`child`.`id`)
        FROM `card` AS `child`
        WHERE `child`.`parent_card_id` = `card`.`id`
    ) 
FROM card
WHERE card.id IN  ('0a4f5e08-496f-4a43-994a-1ed1bc28f8fb')
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | card | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 144 | const | 1 | Using index |
| 2 | SUBQUERY | child | ref | card_parent_card_id_idx | card_parent_card_id_idx | 145 | const | 1 | Using index |

Is the result in te rows column incorrect on the first query, or does he looks in alle the card items in the subquery. Is there a way to get maybe a better index for the parent child relation.

EDIT 23 feb

Added a extra line in the subquery, both cards (parent/ child) always have the same collection id, this give me a better result in total rows examined in the explain

```
EXPLAIN
 SELECT
    parent.id,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(`child`.`id`)
        FROM `card` AS `child`
        WHERE `child`.`parent_card_id` = `parent`.`id`
            AND child.collection_id = parent.collection_id
    ) 
FROM card as parent
WHERE parent.id IN  ('0a4f5e08-496f-4a43-994a-1ed1bc28f8fb', '51d755a6-74ef-4c36-bc5b-a3a313d340f4')
```

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | card | range | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 144 | 2 |  | Using where |
| 2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | child | `ref|filter` | card_collection_id_foreign,card_parent_card_id_idx | `card_collection_id_foreign|card_parent_card_id_idx` | `144|145` | parent.collection_id | 2 (0%) | Using where; Using rowid filter |

Comment: `card.id` is ambiguous.  Please give the outer `card` and alias of `parent`.  Also change `COUNT(...)` to simply `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: Count is only a shorter version of the original sum(...), card.id in the subquery is the same as the outer card.id. It would also give a error if it was ambigous, tried to give outer card a alias but did not give a change in te rows examed

Comment: `COUNT` and `SUM` may be optimized differently.  Please don't simplify things; we could give you the "wrong" answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring your dependent subquery to be independent.

```sql
SELECT card.id, children.child_count
  FROM card
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT COUNT(id) child_count
                      parent_card_id
                 FROM card
                GROUP BY parent_card_id
            ) children ON card.id = children.parent_card_id
 WHERE card.id IN  (
      '0a4f5e08-496f-4a43-994a-1ed1bc28f8fb',
      '51d755a6-74ef-4c36-bc5b-a3a313d340f4')
```

And, if you can change your table definition so those VARCHAR UUIDs have `CHARACTER SET ascii` you'll save space and time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, only makes its slower. Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort. Also the subquery is not the original subquery, but only a sorter one to make the question simpeler.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you're trying to get the number of children cards for each card. I think a GROUP BY on the `parent_card_id` should do the trick

```sql
SELECT parent_card_id, COUNT(*)
FROM card
WHERE parent_card_id IN ('0a4f5e08-496f-4a43-994a-1ed1bc28f8fb', '51d755a6-74ef-4c36-bc5b-a3a313d340f4')
GROUP BY parent_card_id
```

The caveat is that if a card has no children, it will just not appear in the query. It's probably easier and cheaper to deal with that case in the code rather than trying to perfect the query.